# Integral2 from discrete data in matlab

Tags: matlab, interpolation, integral

I would like to take double integral from discrete data (I don't want to use trapz) with integral2.
I tried the following code

```
theta = linspace(0,pi,nTheta);
phi = linspace(0,2*pi,nPhi);
p=zeros(nPhi,nTheta);%only to show the dimension of my matrix
[np,nt]=ndgrid(phi,theta);
f1 = griddedInterpolant(np,nt,p);
f2= @(np,nt) f1(np,nt);
integral2(f2,0,2*pi,0,pi)
```

but i am not sure if it is the fastest way to do so, because i get some warning

```
*Warning: Query data is in MESHGRID format, NDGRID format will yield better performance.
Convert your query data (Xq, Yq) as follows:
   F = griddedInterpolant(. . .);
   Xq = Xq'; Yq = Yq';
   Vq = F(Xq,Yq);*
```

I tried the suggestion but still i get the warning.

although i get correct results, i am not even sure if i am doing it correctly. Since it is a costly run and the integral is in a for loop, i suspect those lots of warnings as output slow down the run too(I disabled the warning output but still not sure if it does not slow down).

My only aim is to find the fastest way to use integral2(and not trapz) where theta, phi and p is given as discrete data.

Comment: `integral2` and `trapz` should produce the same results. Any reason that you want to use `integral2` ?

Comment: @rahnema1 Since there is singularity in my function, i would like to use 'spline' interpolation in the gridded interpolant. For a specific mesh size, comparing trapz, integral2 with linear interpolation and integral2 with spline, the latter produces less error.  I can use more points for my function,(which reduces error) but it is getting very slow...